# Is there any way to get Rhino Mock to automatically generate the "Expect.Calls" at runtime?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, automocking

Is there any way to get Rhino Mock to automatically generate the "Expect.Calls" at runtime?

So if we were to personify Rhino mock, it would say..."According to this setting, I'm going to generate an expect.call for any method I run across that belongs to a class that implements any of these interfaces."

Answer (score 1):

You could either use [`dynamic mock`](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Introduction.ashx) concept from *RhinoMocks* to mock whole interface implementation, or [`autofixture`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx) with [RhinoMocks](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/13/RhinoMocksbasedAutomockingWithAutoFixture.aspx) could helps you. If you are able to provide more clear example of your idea, someone could advice you better solution.